# XSLT Transform XML file to TXT file with Custom Name

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm learning XSLT with the goal to transform a XML file to TXT file as part of a technical interview. Part of the ask is create the TXT file in a specific format e.g. Name_YYYYMMDD.txt. I'm using sites like XSL Transform to work out how to make the transformation. However I'm wondering if it is possible to actually generate a text file from XSLT code and specify its filename? I can't seem to find any documentation and I wonder if I'll need to use something like Visual Studio to actually generate a file instead of just getting an output like I'm doing in XSL Transform of W3School Try it. I found a  If someone can help point me to the right direction that will be much appreciated!

Looking to see if I should spend time trying to figure out how to generate an actual file from XSLT or is this just something that will be part of the environment setup e.g. Visual Studio or proprietary systems that I will be working with.

Comment: Many XSLT processors have command line interfaces where you certainly can set the result file name as a command line option. Browser based interfaces to XSLT processors operate in the context of the browser sandbox and tend that way to present the result in a textarea or frame or an advanced editor component. IDEs like VS, depending on the edition, might also allow you to specify a result file name. Not sure about VS community edition, for VS Code the https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=deltaxml.xslt-xpath extension might help.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the output file is usually controlled from the XSLT processor's API, not from the stylesheet code itself.

However, in XSLT 2.0 you can direct the output using

```
<xsl:result-document href="Name_{$var}.text" method="text">
  ...
</xsl:result-document>
```

if that's what you prefer. This is especially useful, of course, if you are splitting one input file into multiple output files.

You haven't mentioned XSLT versions but if you're going into a technical interview you need to have some awareness that different versions exist.